# install4j: Can the HSM module for Windows EV code signing be configured to pick the first available certificate?

Tags: code-signing, install4j, code-signing-certificate, hardware-security-module

We are setting up a 2nd code signing machine with a 2nd EV code signing USB token (Sectigo SafeNet).

Now we face the problem that the Subject/Issuer/Serial of the 2nd token are different than the first.

Is there a way to just pick the first available certificate on the token? It only contains one.

Otherwise we have to complicate the build by passing different certificate info via compiler variables for each build machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 10.x, this is not possible. I've created an issue for this feature request.